# SharePoint 2013 Last Crawl DateTime in display template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, search, crawl

I would like to display the last crawl time in a display template preferably. if not is there a way to display the last crawl time for a specific content source? this is not for sp online.

Comment: What is the use case? A content source can execute a crawl without the content itself being crawled due to any number of issues.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question... I would like to display the last crawled time for a specific item. if this is not possible, I would like to display(somehow) on a page where visitors can see the last crawled time for a content source.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @Trevor, that you should provide a more detailed use case.

To answer your question, you can do the following -

1. You can directly map a managed property to - `internal:323`

[image]

Or

2. you can try following [this link](http://www.techmikael.com/2015/01/crawl-time-for-sharepoint-online-and.html) and upload a search scheme that gives you CrawlTime managed property -

[image]

That will give you a managed property `CrawlTime`

[image]

Comment: I had already done this. it does not work. The managed property is empty after a full crawl.